# Question about the inner workings of Spotify-Adblock

Tags: rust, spotify, adblock

I am trying to understand how the [Spotify-adbock](https://github.com/abba23/spotify-adblock) works in detail.

I looked the repo and I have figured out the following things up till now :-

1. It uses a config.toml to store a list of urls that are allowed to receive data from and blocks the other requests (Not sure about the blocking part but would like to confirm)
2. In [src/lib.rs](https://github.com/abba23/spotify-adblock/blob/main/src/cef.rs) it implements the above mentioned point

The questions I have :-

1. The use and workings of [src/cef.rs](https://github.com/abba23/spotify-adblock/blob/main/src/cef.rs) . I know its referenced in the lib.rs but it seems to declare a lot of variables and structs but they are not used in the lib.rs
2. It seems to generate its own .so file that replaces the spotify's proprietary .so , so did the author reverse engineer the spotify .so to replicate functionality or is it kind of like a plug in.

I am not super familiar with rust, just basic syntax. I am decently proficient in C++ so I have not fully understood the code but have just got a basic idea from what I have seen.

Comment: Note that `cef.rs` has a comment near the top that says: _"automatically generated by rust-bindgen 0.57.0"_. It's an automatic conversion of `include/capi/cef_urlrequest_capi.h` to Rust. Since the conversion is automatic, it contains everything from the `.h` whether the Rust code really uses it or not.

Comment: @Jmb thanks for that must have missed it, do you have any idea about the .so situation